# How to prevent Calibre replacing my cover image

Tags: calibre, image, linux, cover

I am trying to add an image as a cover of my ebook in "edit book" mode, so I choose "Add cover" from "Tools" menu, add my image and for a moment it seems to work, however very quickly the image is replaced by an image generated from title and author metadata (it seems), which is not what I want.

Comment: Which version of Calibre are you using?

Comment: Calibre 2.5. it seems I found a solution which works, so far. Instead of choosing "edit book" I chose "edit metadata" and then changed the cover. Is there any difference between both options?

Comment: Yes there is. I actually missed that you were doing edit book. Calibre keeps the cover as a separate file in its database and reinserts that when rendering the book. You should answer your own question with that information (or let me know and I can do that).

Comment: Yes, please, do. I think I understand it now, but still can't figure out why another option for inserting cover when one edits book. Is setting it in metadata not enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calibre has had an option to insert a cover long before it offered editing some ebook formats. That option comes with additional utilities of finding a fitting cover using some internet services.
If such a cover is not selected, calibre generates its own and inserts that in the epub file.

With the relatively new editing possibilities in Calibre, the cover still comes from this explicit selection (via the metadata editor). And any hand-crafted cover page gets overwritten by the "insert cover from metadata" functionality.

That cover is actually stored along with the ebook and the metadata in the directory where the ebook is stored. You can probably just replace that there, or select the cover you want via the metadata change functionality.